# How to Verifying Correctness of App in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

The question might appear a bit vague, so allow me to explain a bit.

I'm part of a startup that is trying to build a way to set up an Android tutorial, whereby, users also get to build a proper, functioning app alongside. Unlike teaching web-based technologies, we can't emulate the experience of building an android app on the web.

For this, we were hoping to create a stub project, which our users would download and then, we can devise ways to verify that users have correctly performed certain actions, by modifying the "Run Configuration". However, we haven't been able to find any useful hooks through which we can test for correctness.

By *correctness*, I mean some basic tests, like whether the user properly created a list adapter, whether an edit box was created, whether the textview showed up, etc.

At this point, I wanted to ask if there are any good approaches I can try? I thought of extending the ADT, or build a plugin for it. But that would be a significant effort, and I'd like to exhaust any other alternatives before diving into this.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing BlackBox tests?

Comment: this won't exactly qualify as black-box testing since I need to verify internal structures as well. Like, did the user create a proper list of objects, etc.